# GraphQL returns null when I try prefetching a property in Post document

Tags: next.js, graphql

I am making voting system where up and down propery saves each user's id as string array. `voteHandler()` function is a function responsible for updating and refetching the change of the two arrays, but state is not updated when i click bottons.
Here is my code:

#### client code:

```js
interface ICardInfo {
  post: IPost;
}

export default function Component({ post }: ICardInfo) {
  const [postVote, voteResult] = useMutation(POST_VOTE);

  //Vote
  function voteHandler(
    event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>,
    postId: string | undefined
  ) {
    const buttonName = event.currentTarget.name;
    postVote({
      variables: {
        postId: postId,
        userId: session.data?.user._id,
        upDown: buttonName
      },
      refetchQueries: [{ query: GET_VOTE, variables: { postId: postId } }],
      onCompleted: (data) => {
        console.log("GET VOTE", data);
      }
    });
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className="flex flex-col">
        <button name="up" onClick={(e) => voteHandler(e, post._id)}>
          <ChevronUpIcon className="w-5" />
        </button>
        <h3 className="text-center">{voteData?.getVote?.vote?.up.length}</h3>
        <button name="down" onClick={(e) => voteHandler(e, post._id)}>
          <ChevronDownIcon />
        </button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

#### typeDef

```js
  type Query {
    getVote(postId: String): Post
  }


  type Mutation {
    postVote(postId: String, userId: String upDown: String): String
  }
```

#### Resolver

```js
  Mutation: {
      try{
        const {postId, userId, upDown}: IPostVote = args;
        console.log(postId, userId, upDown)
        await connectDB();
        const post: IPost | any = await Post.findById({_id: postId});
        // console.log(post)
        const up = post.vote.up
        const down = post.vote.down
        if(upDown === "up"){
            //More logics
            up.push(userId)
            await post.save()
        }

        if(upDown === "down"){
            //More logics
            down.push(userId)
            await post.save()
          }
            await post.save()
        }
        return
      }catch(err: any){
        console.log(err.message)
      }
    },

   Query: {
    getVote:async (parent, args) => {
      const {postId} = args
      await connectDB()
      const post: any | IPost = await Post.findById({_id: postId});
      console.log("Refetch vote", post.vote)
      return post.vote
    }
   },
  }
```

#### gql

```js
export const GET_VOTE = gql`
query GetVote($postId: String){
  getVote(postId: $postId){
    vote
  }
}
`;

export const POST_VOTE = gql`
  mutation postVote($postId: String, $userId: String $upDown: String) {
    postVote(postId: $postId, userId: $userId upDown: $upDown)
  }
`;
```

I know array are being added and removed because i can see on terminal, but when I click botton, it keep saying on the console window
form

```js
      onCompleted: (data) => {
        console.log("GET VOTE", data);
      }
```

#### result

`GET VOTE {postVote: null}`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed like following and now it works

```js
  type Query {
    getVote(postId: String): vote
  }

  type vote {
     up: [String]
     down: [String]
 }
```

```js
   Query: {
    getVote:async (parent, args) => {
      const {postId} = args
      await connectDB()
      const post: any | IPost = await Post.findById({_id: postId});
      console.log("Refetch vote", post.vote)
      return {up: post.vote.up, down: post.vote.down}
    }
```